# How can I call zmq_close() using the C# binding for ØMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq

I have a C# project which uses ØMQ. I would like to [close a socket](http://api.zeromq.org/2-2%3azmq-close), but I don't see how I can do that with the C# binding. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/blob/master/src/ZeroMQ/ZmqSocket.cs#L503 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you use the [clrzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq%20clrzmq) C# binding.

You can either explicitly close the socket by calling `Close`, or wrap it in a using statement which will dispose (and close) it for you when it goes out of scope, like this:

```
using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
{
    using (var socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.PUB))
    {                   
        // Do stuff here, just an example:
        socket.Bind(myEndPoint);
        socket.Send("Hello", Encoding.UTF8);
    }   // Socket is Closed and Disposed
}   // Context is Terminated and Disposed
```